# Loading of RAM on MacBook pro 16 inch

Tags: macbook-pro

I have bought my new MacBook pro 16 inch 16gb of RAM core i9 4gb of GPU and 1TB of SSD yesterday and question is Why when I don't use any apps does my computer consume about 6.5GB of RAM? Does macOS take so lots of space or something else? Does it mean that I have only 10GB of RAM for my own use?

Thank you.

Comment: You really need to better define 'consume'. Long & short is the Mac is extremely efficient at handling its memory, but you have to remember the adage "Empty RAM is wasted RAM." The Mac will not clear down RAM it might want to use again for cached items, unless other pressure is applied to it.

Comment: So when I launch heavy app  this memory will be released for effective execution of that, right?

Comment: It's just not that simple, but yes, kind of. It will use your SSD storage for virtual memory too. All you need to know is that if Activity Monitor still shows green, there's nothing at all to worry about.